# python environment variables

Tags: python, ubuntu, environment-variables, virtualenv

Could I take environment variables across the files.

Could I set env. variable in one file, and get it in another?

For example.

first.py

```
import  os
os.environ["FOO"] = "1"
```

second.py

`import os
 print os.environ['FOO']`

Comment: Could you please re-word your question? To be honest, I do not understand what you are talking about

Comment: Are you running `first.py` and `second.py` as separate processes? There seems to be no connection between them.

Comment: Could I set env. variable in one file, and get it in another?